# quarkus, @produces interface with multiple implementation

Tags: quarkus, cdi

So I have one interface:

```
public interface GService {
    String doIt();
}
```

2 implementations:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class GServiceBImpl implements GService {
    @Override
    public String doIt() {
        return "B";
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class GServiceAImpl implements GService {
    @Override
    public String doIt() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

and the factory producer:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyServiceFactory {

    @Inject
    GServiceAImpl gServiceA;

    @Inject
    GServiceBImpl gServiceB;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public GService getGService() {
        final long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return currentTimeMillis % 2 == 0 ?
               gServiceA :
               gServiceB;
    }

}
```

Now the utilizer:

```
@Path("/doit")
public class GResource {

    @Inject
    GService gService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String doIt() {
        return gService.doIt();
    }

}
```

By implementing the utilizier class, I receive the following error at the end of maven compilation:

```
*Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: Ambiguous dependencies for type it.fstarred.services.GService and qualifiers [@Default]
    - java member: it.fstarred.resources.GResource#gService
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[it.fstarred.resources.GResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=it.fstarred.resources.GResource]
    - available beans:
        - CLASS bean [types=[it.fstarred.services.GService, it.fstarred.services.GServiceAImpl, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Named("A"), @Any], target=it.fstarred.services.GServiceAImpl]
        - CLASS bean [types=[it.fstarred.services.GService, it.fstarred.services.GServiceBImpl, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any, @Named("B")], target=it.fstarred.services.GServiceBImpl]
        - PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[it.fstarred.services.GService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=it.fstarred.services.GService getGService(), declaringBean=it.fstarred.services.MyServiceFactory]*
```

Comment: You have 3 beans that all have bean type `GService`. Given how `MyServiceFactory` looks like, you would probably be fine if `GServiceAImpl` and `GServiceBImpl` didn't have `GService` among their set of bean types, which you can achieve by annotating these classes with `@Typed(...)`. Another option is that you annotate the producer method with `@Alternative @Priority(1)`, which will make it preferred over the other beans of type `GService`.

Comment: @Ladicek that comment qualifies as an answer

Comment: by adding the 2 annotations `@Alternative @Priority(1)`  looks like it works now :)
I'm not sure `@Typed` was good for me, is an annotation similar to `@Named` ? Btw I didn't want to choose the implementation bymyself, I need the implementaiton to be resolved on runtime.
Thank you very much